# read json data and display with breaks

Tags: json, angular

I want to display a text that is written as a JSON string with paragraphs. How is the best way to do this?

This is my dashboard.component.ts:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

items: Array<IService>;
blogs: Array<any>;
comment: any;

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.dataService.getAllServices()
.subscribe(
  (data: IService[]) => this.items = data,
  (err: any) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('All done getting the services.')
  );

this.dataService.getAllBlogposts()
  .subscribe(
    (data: any[]) => this.blogs = data,
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('All done getting the blogposts.')
  );

this.dataService.saveComment(this.comment)
  .subscribe(comment => this.comment.push(this.comment));

}
}
```

This is my blogposts.json:
My idea was to put the json string in html elements so I can display the html. Is there a better way?

```
[{
 "postName": "Was sind eigentlich diese Observables in Angular?",
 "postId": "1",
 "postText": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
 </br> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
  </p>"
  }]
```

This is my template where I display the blogposts:

```
<div class="row">
<h1>Services</h1>
</div>

<div class="card col-md-3 col-lg-3 justify-content-center float-left" 
*ngFor="let item of blogs">

 <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{ item.postName }}
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="card-body">
    <span>{{ 'ID: ' + item.postId }}</span> <br>
    <span *ngFor="let el of blogs">
      {{ item.postText }} <br />
    </span>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="widget-area no-padding blank">
          <div class="status-upload">
            <form>
              <textarea placeholder="What do you think of my blogpost?" >{{ comment }}</textarea>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success green"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share</button>
            <br>
            </form>
          </div><!-- Status Upload  -->
        </div><!-- Widget Area -->
      </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display line breaks, you have to use the `innerHTML` directive:

```
<span *ngFor="let el of blogs" [innerHTML]="el.postText"></span>
```

Angular will render the HTML as it is instead of interpreting it like a simple string.